# What are all the effects of hacking a system?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I've noticed that the hacking drone sometimes provide additional benefits while hacking a system in addition to removing it from play for a while.

For example, hacking an medbay will cause the room to damage instead of heal.  Hacking a battery will drain power rather than provide power.

What are the effects of hacking on each system/subsystem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All the info is given in the tooltips, but here's a run-down:

- Shields: Drain power from shields, disabling them if enough power is drained in time
- Engines: Makes the target's Evasion stat visible just by being attached, and makes it zero when hacking
- Weapons: Makes charge level visible even if sensors don't allow it, and drains when hacking
- Oxygen: Drains O<sub>2</sub> from the ship, and shows the enemy's O<sub>2</sub> level
- Medbay: Hurts instead of healing
- Clone Bay: Kills any clones that are being restored
- Drone Control: May cause drones to self-destruct in addition to the temporary disabling.
- Hacking: Same as Drone Control
- Mind Control: MC's an enemy crew member instead of your own; combined with your own MC this can be particularly devastating.
- Teleporter: Instantly recalls enemy boarders from your ship back to theirs
- Cloaking: Prevents cloaking. I think it also drags the ship out of cloak if used during a cloak. No effect if Cloak is recharging, so make sure icon is not flashing blue when you hack.
- Artillery: Same as Weapons but only for that item
- Piloting: Same as Engines, but generally more useful because you can also trap the pilot.
- Sensors: Disables them like a Nebula. No discernible effect on enemy ships because [the Computer is a Cheating Bastard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107675/is-there-any-benefit-to-damaging-enemy-sensors). On the plus side, it does prevent enemy MC since they can't see you (unless you're on their ship, or they fire a bomb, temporarily revealing a room), but you're better off hacking their MC in the first place.
- Doors: Makes doors into Blast Doors, but only allows *your* crew through when boarding
- Battery: Drains power instead of adding it.

Comment: Your answer is more complete.  I'll delete mine.  Cloaking does drop out of cloak when used.  Sensors disabling prevents mind control against your ship.

Comment: Sensors won't prevent MC against MC'd targets on their ship or your boarders on their ship though.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Thanks. Expanded a bit on that point. Bombs temporarily reveal rooms too.

Comment: Also it is worth noting that if cloaking is on cooldown, hacking it won't delay them from recharging.  Because cloaking cooldown can be longer than hacking, it is best to activate your hacking on their cloaking systems once they've already cloaked.

Comment: wow, that MC combo sounds wicked, I have to try it when the opportunity presents itself.

Comment: >unless you're on *their* ship

Comment: @user1306322 then why not suggest the edit?

Comment: @Schism it'd be declined as minor, I've tried before many times.